# Xcode 11 successful archives will not show in organizer,

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, quasar

I have a problem when it comes to uploading my app to the Apple Store, this is the first time I work with IOS. The Build is working correctly, however, when I perform the project archive (which by the way runs without errors) it does not appear on the Organizer screen so that I can upload the app to the store. I have already created the distribution certificate and the production profile. I already removed the project and added it again, installed an older version of XCODE, tested it on another project but always the same thing.

I am using Quasar / Cordova, version of Xcode 11.3 MAC version Catalina 10.15. In some places I found some people advising to disable the "skip install" property in the build settings, but it also didn't work. Could they help?

Comment: are you sure about the version of Xcode? Do you see any iOS section in the Organizer? Show a screen cap.

Answer (score 1):

Please perform this steps :

- Xcode -> Build Settings -> Installation Directory -> Set value **$(LOCAL_APPS_DIR)**  or **/Applicatins**

OR

You can open organizer manually also. After successfully archive please perform this steps :

- Xcode -> Window -> Organizer

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue after OSX update to 10.15.5

Follow the steps below:

1. Delete the sub-folders in Archives.
2. Delete DerivedData folder.